# Как отвязать SocketIO от cdn(jquery)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Как отвязать SocketIO от cdn(jquery) и поставить свой путь до jquery?
С cdn работает нормально

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

пробовал:

```
<script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

и вот так

```
<script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/cdn/jquery-1.11.1.js></script>
```

не работает.

Пытаюсь сделать по примеру https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Собственно файлы 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно структуру проекта?

Comment: И вы установили через npm jquery?

Comment: да установил через npm jquery предварительно прописав в package.json строчку "jquery": "1.11.1"

Comment: попробуй либо ../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js либо node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js

Comment: `<script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: Не работают ваши способы.